Dash Plotly Multiple Pages
Using Dash Plotly, I created a dashboard and a data table. I want to display them on two separate pages. When I run the code, only the dashboard is visible. How can I display the data table in a different window or tab?
import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from dash import dash_table
from app1 import app as app1
from app2 import app as app2

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
html.Div(id='page-content')
])

@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
          [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/app1':
        return app1.layout
    elif pathname == '/app2':
        return app2.layout
    else:
        return '404 - Not Found'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)


See https://dash.plotly.com/urls

You can use multi-page urls in plotly dash to achieve this: https://dash.plotly.com/urls
Here is a minimal working example of dash multi-pages (mostly copied from one of the examples in dash plotly - multi-pages). You could modify this based on your layout and data.
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])

index_page = html.Div([
    html.H1('Welcome to the Multi-Page App Demo'),
    html.A('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1', target='_blank'),
    html.Br(),
    html.A('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2', target='_blank'),
])

page_1_layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Page 1'),
    html.P('This is the content of Page 1.'),
    html.Br(),
    html.A('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2', target='_blank'),
    html.Br(),
    html.A('Go back to home', href='/', target='_blank'),
])

page_2_layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Page 2'),
    html.P('This is the content of Page 2.'),
    html.Br(),
    html.A('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1', target='_blank'),
    html.Br(),
    html.A('Go back to home', href='/', target='_blank'),
])

@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'), Input('url', 'pathname'))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/page-1':
        return page_1_layout
    elif pathname == '/page-2':
        return page_2_layout
    else:
        return index_page

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


